# Fastest way to convert a C buffer into a python bytes object

Tags: python, python-3.x, ctypes

I have some C code passes data to a callback. The callback is defined as:

`typedef void (*packetHandlerCb)(uint8_t *data, uint32_t len);`

I want to set up a python handler for this callback, so I've done something like:

```
def handle_packet(packet_data, packet_len):
    return bytes(ctypes.cast(packet_data, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_ubyte * packet_len))[0])

PACKET_CB = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(None, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_ubyte), ctypes.c_uint)
cb = PACKET_CB(handle_packet)
```

I'm curious if there is a more efficient way to convert the C buffer into a python bytes object

Comment: A [`memoryview`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=memoryview#memoryview) might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like I can simply do `bytes(packet_data[:packet_len])` which seems to be about 30% faster on my computer